# Can I salvage overexposed images accidentally taken in manual mode?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, gimp, overexposure

I have a question. My wife used our camera and left the setting on Manual, which I didn't realize when I was going out to take pictures yesterday in the bright sun. We had some really great pictures, but as you can imagine, ALL of the pictures are almost completely washed out. You can see very little from each picture. I'm not a camera expert by ANY means, but I was wondering if there's any way to fix the pictures?? I have used GIMP on my PC basically because it's free, but am not sure if it's even possible to salvage some of the pictures.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you got only the JPG version or do you also have the "raw" files?

Comment: Need more info - jpg or raw? Have you already dialed back the exposure or messed with the levels/curves to try to salvage them?

Comment: Please post an example or two. But it's quite likely that the answer is no. If the camera saved only pure white, then you can't magically extract an image from that.

Comment: typically, there are CR2 files associated with each JPG, but I'm not finding them on the disk - I'm not sure why. I haven't done much of anything except Google if there's a way to fix it. I have some images that have all white and some that have some color in there. I also can't figure out how to upload an image here for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the .jpg files, likely you cannot pull very much from the image even with special recovery software. If you took the .NEF/.CR2 'raw' images, I could definitely give you a hand pulling the picture out. Unfortunately, JPEG compresses the image for storing and removes and raw data - sort of like a picture of your picture.. Sorry to hear that!